# Go bin in PATH, but "go version" fails

Tags: bash, go, path

How can I use go using the standard installation instructions in bash? What do I do wrong?

I followed the [installation instructions for go on Linux](https://golang.org/doc/install). Therefore I downloaded the go tar.gz, untared it to `/usr/local` and added `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin` to `/etc/bash.bashrc` and made a `source /etc/bash.bashrc`.

However, `go version` does not give the proper result. See:

```
user@machine:~$ which go
/usr/local/go/bin/go
user@machine:~$ go version
user@machine:~$ /usr/local/go/bin/go version
go version go1.11.5 linux/amd64

user@machine:~$ type -a go
go is a function.
go () 
{ 
    eval dir=\$$1;
    cd "$dir"
}
go is /usr/local/go/bin/go
```

Comment: What does `type go` print?

Comment: `which` is not really what you want. You want `type -a go`.

Comment: edited question (I have german output and translated).

Comment: There you go! you already have defined a function called `go` (probably defined in your `.bashrc`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shell functions take priority over commands in your `$PATH`.

`which` doesn't necessarily find shell functions (in fact I don't think it can find them at all). `type -a` is more reliable, at least if you're using bash or another sh-derived shell.

The problem is that you have an unrelated shell function called `go`.

If you still want that function, I suggest giving it a different name, `Go` would work.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: For the record, I didn't see your comment (which solved it) until after I posted the answer (which was admittedly obvious given the updated question).

Comment: Together with [How to find the function definition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/322817/how-to-find-the-file-where-a-bash-function-is-defined) found the culprit. `bash_aliases`.